# Share a value of variable in flutter web app between two browser

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-state

I develop a web app with flutter. I want to share variable between two browser at the same system. I mean when I run project on **chrome** (i.e. http://localhost:58284) and I increment a counter value, then i open (http://localhost:58284/#/) in **firefox** browser, i see the counter value in **firefox**. Note that, I don't want to use api, firebase db (or any online storage).

First I want to know if this purpose is possible. If yes, how.
A real example of this purpose is `Youtube`. When I watch a video until the half of video and I want to watch remind of this video on another system, it remembers how much I watched the video. Does it use online api to save how much I watched?

Comment: Hi, I think it's not possible to retrieve same data on different browsers without using cloud APIs. You just can get same data on a browser using sessions but different browsers has their own session. Youtube save your data on it's servers.

Comment: Thanks Erfan, I knew it, but that was a small task that employer asked me to do for hiring. I said that's not possible without online storage., but they emphasized doing that without any online storage :))).
Anyway, I withdrew this job